# Bootstrap 4 - Align horizontally and vertically

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I can't align the following content both horizontally and vertically.

Can someone tell me the best approach for this ?

```
    <div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img width="300" src="../assets/medlogo.png">

      <h1 class="text-center login-title">Acessar o programa</h1>
      <div class="account-wall">
        <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
          alt="">
        <form class="form-signin">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                  Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap4 is now using css Flexbox so you can use the same. Flexbox has vertical and horizontal alignment support out of the box.

Basically, a flexbox container can have `flex-direction` as **row** (the default value) or **column**. With the former, property `align-items` can be used to vertical align its children and `justify-content` for horizontal alignment. While with the latter, `align-items` is used for horizontal align and `justify-content` for vertical alignment.

You can read more about Flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thai Duong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
      <img width="300" src="../assets/medlogo.png">

      <h1 class="text-center login-title">Acessar o programa</h1>
      <div class="account-wall">
        <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
          alt="">
        <form class="form-signin">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                  Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
```

I removed the col-md-4 and replaced it with `d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center`. This is bootstrap 4 beta utilities for flexbox. Though you can also do in-line style

More info
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Hi, no results. All become unaligned.

Comment: can you provide a plunkr or codepen?

Comment: Hi @brijmcq. I'm new on plunkr. The code is that but not running yet https://plnkr.co/edit/Sszrawikt6Z6xWUZH8JD

Comment: i have a project with bootstrap included in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bri-bootstrap-login, fork it and edit it with your code and let's see what's the problem

Comment: Fixed it and now it's running -> https://plnkr.co/edit/Q77tXQ4rJ2Yt1n7u6zYq?p=preview .